# Theme functions don't work as expected in partial included via get_template_part() after custom query using Ajax

Tags: theme-development, ajax, child-theme

I am developing an custom theme which could be a child theme of any arbitrary theme out there that has custom theme functions defined.

The home page is simply configured as list of latest posts. I need to filter the posts for categories and custom fields with Ajax .

The Ajax part including jQuery for the filter UI and the ajax action seem to work just fine.

However, iIf I run my custom query and use the parent theme's blog template as intented, the template part I am calling seems not to know all parent theme functions within my custom loop. While the 'filtered' posts list is being rendered, it does not use all Parent Theme settings.

This is, because `parent_custom_theme_function();` in the template part seems not to work from within my custom query loop.

The My-Child/index.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * The theme's index.php file.
 *
 */

// Do not allow directly accessing this file.
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit( 'Direct script access denied.' );
}
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section id="content" <?php ThemeClass()->layout->add_class( 'content_class' ); ?> <?php ThemeClass()->layout->add_style( 'content_style' ); ?>>

    <?php get_template_part('templates/blog-list', 'teaser-post' ); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'templates/blog-list', 'filter-panel' ); ?>

    <div id="slp-sorted-posts-container"></div>

    <?php get_template_part( 'templates/blog', 'layout' ); ?>
</section>
<?php do_action( 'theme_after_content' ); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The jQuery part:

```
function slpAjaxSortPosts() {
    jQuery( '#filter input[type="radio"]' ).on( 'change', function () {
        jQuery( '#filter' ).submit();
    } )
    jQuery( '#filter' ).submit( function ( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var filter = jQuery( '#filter' );
        jQuery.ajax( {
            url: filter.attr( 'action' ),
            data: filter.serialize(),
            type: filter.attr( 'method' ),
            beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
                filter.find( '#most-read-posts' ).text( 'Sortiere...' );
            },
            success: function ( data ) {
                filter.find( '#most-read-posts' ).text( 'Meistgelesene Beiträge' );
                jQuery( '#slp-sorted-posts-container' ).html( data );
            }
        } );
    })
}



/*
    RUN CUSTOM JS CODE
 */
app = jQuery( document ).ready( function () {

    slpAjaxSortPosts();

} )
```

The Ajax action in my custom plugin:

```
Class MyCustomizer {

        function __construct() {

            // WP Ajax Hook is always connected to 'admin-ajax.php' even when used in frontend
            if ( is_admin() ) {
                add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_filter', array( $this, 'ajax_sort_posts' ) );
                add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_filter', array( $this, 'ajax_sort_posts' ) );
            }

        }

       function ajax_sort_posts() {

            global $wp_query;

            $attr = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => 5 // Filter args not yet set
            );
            $wp_query = new WP_Query( $attr );

            if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
                get_template_part( 'templates/blog', 'layout' );
            endif;

            wp_reset_postdata();
        }

}
$my_customizer = new MyCustomizer();
```

Note: `templates/blog-layout.php` reads the original parent theme's file as I have no override for this in my child theme.

Now, the result is: the queried posts are being rendered within the appropriate container. But any parent theme functions referring to the parent theme class return an empty value instead the actual value from, say, the theme settings. Hence, the template part does not set all css classes properly.

Couldn't found any helpful content on Duckduckgo nor on Stackoverflow.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, how to implement an Ajax post filter within a child building on any parent theme right?

Comment: The issue in your original question was highly specific to Avada's specific implementation of its classes. There isn't going to be a generic solution,  unless you know exactly what "`parent_custom_theme_function()`" does.

Comment: The template partial in concern is usually called within the main loop. I am starting a custom loop with my Ajax call. Hence, I assume any issue global variables may be missing in my custom loop that are set by the main loop. So the issue may well be independent of any particular 3rd party theme but may happen to other WP devs, too?

Comment: the other question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/366047/avada-get-template-part-after-custom-query-using-ajax-does-not-use-theme-func

Comment: @Dropbear It might be, but it's impossible to say without know what's in that function, and you haven't included it in the question.

Comment: @Dropbear every request loads WP from scratch, a clean slate, no variables survive to the next request. Making a variable `global` does not change that. There is also no mention of `parent_custom_theme_function` in the code in your question. As Jacob said, there is no general WP solution here, specialist knowledge of that theme is neeeded/mandatory to answer or understand this question

Comment: @JacobPeattie Right, left it out on purpose because I am afraid that my question will be banned again due to showing 3rd party theme code... Yes, there may be specific 3rd party code. But is guess similiar issues may happen with other themes too

Comment: @Dropbear showing or not showing the code won't make a difference here. It just means your question is impossible to understand and would get closed as "unclear what you're asking" because it's not possible to understand. Note that your other question was not closed because it included 3rd party code, it was closed because it's not a WP question, it's an Avada question

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, since it's the same question and has the same problem. It's not possible to understand or answer this without knowing the internals of the Avada theme. You need help from Avada users and Avada support, there is no general WP answer/solution to your problem. This is why the question is getting closed. I'm not suggesting it's a bad thing to ask, just that this stack is not the appropriate place to ask it.